# updating gedmo timestamptable manually

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

So I am using the doctrine extension [here](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/symfony2.md), which basically generates a created on timestamp. I am now trying to override setting the timestamp by doing the following:

```
public function setTimestampDecay()
    {
         $this->created->sub(new \DateInterval('PT4M'));
         return $this;
    }
```

so I wanted to subtract 4 minute from the createdTimestamp in this entity, so here's what I did:

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $picture = $em->getRepository('AppMainBundle:ShopPicture')->findOneById(821478);
        $picture->setTimestampDecay();
        $em->flush();
```

now when I print the `picture->getCreated()` after setting the timestamp decay, it shows the correct time. However the issue is that it is not persisting to the database. When I checked n the database it was actually the same timestamp as before I set it to decay. Why is this? Can't created time stamp on the doctrine extension be modified manually?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to set the creation timestamp to 4 minutes before the object is created?  That seems a bit misleading to me.

In any case, forget using Gedmo Timestampable for setting the creation date.  Just set the timestamp in the object's constructor, since the constructor will only be called when the object is created anyways.

Gedmo's Timestampable behavior is triggered on prePersist so chances are it's overriding the timestamp you're setting manually and that is why you are experiencing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar situation. In my case, initially I was storing default value in one timezone and we wanted it to change it to UTC +0:00.

Problem with using Entity manager for such update is, it gets overwritten by the listener.

Solution was to use PDO, here is how I did it.

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Connection;

// Inject this as a service in your controller
$connection = new Connection();

$items = $connection->fetchAll('SELECT id, created, updated FROM table_name');
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $created = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item['created'])->modify('-3 hours');
    $updated = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item['updated'])->modify('-3 hours');
    $sql = 'UPDATE table_name SET created = :created, updated = :updated WHERE item.id = :item_id';
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(":created", $created->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $statement->bindValue(":updated", $updated->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $statement->bindValue(":item_id", $item['id']);
    $statement->execute();
}
```